# Error Trying to get property 'm_status_name' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

Tengo problemas al obtener los datos de un usuario por el método GET, estoy trabajando en una api.
En mi archivo UserResource obtengo éste array:

```
/**
* Transform the resource into an array.
*/
public function toArray($request)
    {
        try {
            $user = Auth::user();
            return [
                '_id' => $this->id,
                 ....
                //éste es el error m_status_name
                'm_status' => $this->maritalstatus->m_status_name,
                'created_at' => $this->created_at
            ];
        } catch(JWTException $e) {
        }
    }
```

Modelo User:

```
 /**
 * Get the maritalstatus record associated with the user.
 */
public function maritalstatus()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(MaritalStatus::class);
}
```

Database migrations CreateMaritalStatusesTable

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('marital_statuses', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('m_status_name');
            // $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

Mensaje de error

```
{
"message": "Trying to get property 'm_status_name' of non-object",
    "exception": "ErrorException",
    "file": "...\\app\\Http\\Resources\\V1\\UserResource.php",
    "line": 37,
    "trace": [
               {}
             ]
}
```

No entiendo porque me sale ése error, ¿será porque mi modelo MaritalStatuses contiene dos palabras con las iniciales mayúsculas? ¿Qué tendría que hacer?

Comment: Gracias BetaM voy a revisar.

Comment: Creo que deberías de enseñar la tabla `users` por que si no tienes una llave foránea a la table `marital_statuses` lo único que podrás conseguir es un NULL haciendo lo que ya han comentado más arriba. Con un `optional` o `?`

Answer (score 1):

Con la información que provees se puede *suponer* que el usuario consultado no tiene vinculado un **`maritalstatus`** y por ende el resultado de dicha relación es **`NULL`** dado eso no es posible acceder a la propiedad **`m_status_name`**.

Considero que dentro del **`UserResource`** puedes administrar ese aspecto de alguna de estas 2 formas:

1. Mediante el helper [*optional*](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-optional) (*el cual aparece en la doc. oficial de Laravel desde la versión 5.5*), para que si no existen valores vinculados al registro entonces el retorno sea *null* en lugar de causar un fallo como el expuesto:

   ```
   optional($this->maritalstatus)->m_status_name
   ```
2. O bien si estás usando una versión igual o mayor a PHP 8 por medio del [*null safe operator*](https://www.php.net/releases/8.0/en.php#nullsafe-operator) que ayudará a que si la evaluación derivas en un error entonces la salida será **`NULL`** de esta forma:

   ```
   $this->maritalstatus?->m_status_name
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que ver el tipo de datos de

```
$this->maritalstatus
```

Si es array debes usarlo de esta manera:

```
$this->maritalstatus['m_status_name']
```

En vez de:

```
$this->maritalstatus->m_status_name
```

En laravel 8 puedes usar

```
dd($this->maritalstatus);
```

Para ver los datos que trae o

```
print_r($this->maritalstatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que este modelo MaritalStatus::class, tenga esta propiedad :m_status_name y no sea null, y que tambien sea de uno a uno tu relacion, con dd o un return podrias probar que te devuelve desde tu metodo