# Trying to get property 'url' of non-object

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-8

Sé que es un típico problema, pero ante diversas formas de solucionarlo sin éxito recurro a preguntar a ver si me pueden brindar una manito.

Tengo una imagen que puede ser cargada de antemano o no. Al no cargarla recibo el error:

> Trying to get property 'url' of non-object

Para evitar el problema si no cargan la imagen incluí una por default. De la siguiente manera:

```
@if($post->images) 
     background-image:url({{ Storage::url($post->images->first()->url) }}) 
@else 
     background-image:url({{asset('img/fondo/fondoPost.webp')}}) 
@endif
```

Sin embargo recibo el error.

También probé:

```
@if(!isset($post->images))
```

Pero me pasa lo mismo.

¿Alguien conoce la forma de solucionar este problema?

muchas gracias

Comment: Buenas, así está bien?

Comment: Revisa si el contenido de este enlace te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/475590/error-trying-to-get-property-m-status-name-of-non-object/475602#475602

Comment: No me ayuda a solventar. La relación $post->images trae datos por lo tanto ingresa al if pero no trae datos la imagen ya que no la tiene $post->images->first()->url. Entonces me falta realizar esa verificación. Probé de todo y no me funciona. Vos que la tenés muy clara @BetaM no me podes brindar otra idea? muchas gracias

Comment: Precisamente en el enlace que coloqué se menciona como manejar ese escenario para cuando la relación es null y no tiene manera de devolver los valores esperados